# Can't read Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code for reading Firebase data:

```
final String[] booknum = {"0"};
    databaseReference.child("All BID").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            booknum[0] =Long.toString(snapshot.getChildrenCount());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), booknum[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), booknum[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

When I am executing this, the first toast(inside ValueEventListener) prints the right answer (eg '8'). But the toast outside always prints 0 no matter what.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ValueEventListener is asynchronous. The lines of code inside of the listener, including the assignment of booknum[0], are not guaranteed to execute before the lines of code written outside of the listener. If you depend on the new value of booknum[0] for some operation, consider moving that operation inside of onDataChange() to ensure it uses the new value.

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I am unable to fix it. Do you know a way to avoid using  onDataChange()? I just need the number of items that are inside "All BIID".

Comment: Using onDataChange() is the correct way. And you are getting the number of items inside "All BID" in onDataChange(). It prints 8.

Comment: I understand that, but the problem is that I am getting the number of items so that I can generate a unique code before putting in new data. And the onDataChange() does not execute until I write new data. That's why in this code first the '0' from outside toast is printed, then the data is added (with unique code 0) and then onDataChange() prints 8.

Sorry, I am new to database management, your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Now we're getting to the root problem :). You can use Firebase's push() to write children's values with guaranteed unique keys for all the children.